# Reactjs - why my input field have no response when put in a function component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider these 2 lines:

```
<input name='workMinute1' value={workMinute} onChange={changeHandler} />
```

```
<Label name='workMinute' value={workMinute} />
```

They are basically doing the same thing, but second line comes from:

```
  function Label(p) {
    return (
        <input name={p.name} value={p.value} onChange={changeHandler} />
    )
  };
```

Result: the input box in the second line will not response when trying to type in.

I can find related answers but I cannot find a succinct answer that describe the inner working of React related to this issue.

Comment: It's not really "inner workings of React", It just looks like the change handler in `Label` is undefined, so the `value` will never update.

Comment: You're right, the onChange event is not defined. The follow up question would be the input field keep losing focus when typing, any idea on why?

Comment: It sounds like the component is unmounting and remounting each render. Is the `Label` component declared within another component?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your changeHandler looks this way:-

```
function changeHandler(e){
setValue(e.target.value);
}
```

Your Label component declaration should be this way:-

`<Label name='workMinute' value={workMinute} changeHandler={changeHandler}/>`

So your updated component will be:-

```
function Label(p) {
    return (
        <input name={p.name} value={p.value} onChange={p.changeHandler} />
    )
  };
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the input field keep losing focus when I type, any idea why?

Comment: Your component Label might be defined (not just declared) within another component and the value you're changing is re-rendering that parent component and with that in every render a new Label component is being made which makes your input field lose focus.